# Updating massive amount of rows on database with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing, spring-batch

I've been asked to rewrite some batch jobs using Spring Batch, Hibernate and Quartz. The current implementation already uses Hibernate, but there is something wrong in the way they work because they take too much time to complete a task.

This task consists in obtaining items from a XML file and update (or insert, but that does not happen often) the correspondent row in a DB table:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>10005011</id>
        <field_1></field_1> <!--
        <field_2></field_2>
        ...
        <field_n></field_n>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>23455245</id>
        <field_1></field_1> <!--
        <field_2></field_2>
        ...
        <field_n></field_n>
    </item>

    ...
    <item>
        <id>101000454</id> <!-- about 70000  items-->
        <field_1></field_1> <!--
        <field_2></field_2>
        ...
        <field_n></field_n>
    </item>
</items>
```

The file is huge, so I've set a chunk size of 1000: the reader takes 1000 items and the writer receives a List of that size to update the table, delegating that to a DAO (ItemDao).

The way it works is the following:

1. It reads **all the items in the table** (obtaining a List)
2. Stores these items in a Map, using their IDs as key.
3. Loops over the list of Items received as parameter and, one by one, copies all not null fields in the existing items. Hibernate, automagically, updates the modified beans.

The issue I'm facing is each chuck needs more time than the previous one with no apparent reason. Here is my log;

```
12:33:53,376 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:33:56,927 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:33:59,258 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:34:01,358 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:34:03,145 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:34:31,872 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:35:15,694 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:36:06,211 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:37:02,154 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:38:07,124 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:39:19,519 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:40:34,432 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:41:59,926 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:43:31,951 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:45:12,337 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:46:56,331 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:48:49,726 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:50:48,649 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:52:52,897 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:55:06,056 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:57:28,105 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
12:59:55,983 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:02:40,224 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:05:29,506 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:08:21,031 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:11:18,521 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:14:31,911 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:18:03,994 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:21:43,960 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:25:32,084 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
13:29:28,366 INFO  [batch.writer.ItemWriter] Updated/inserted 1000 items
```

Note that the first iterations need a few seconds and as the batch goes on, it takes several minutes... I'm updating about 70000 (seventy thousand) items and last iterations take more than half an hour each.

This is the method in the DAO that is being called:

```
public void synchronizeItems(List<Item> newItemList,
        Jurisdiction jurisdiction) throws ServiceException {

    Map<Long, Item> ItemMap = new HashMap<Long, Item>();
    List<Item> existingItemList = getAllItems(jurisdiction
            .getJurisdictionId());
    for (Item o : existingItemList) {
        ItemMap.put(o.getProprietorId(), o);
    }

    for (Item newItem : newItemList) {
        updateItem(newItem, jurisdiction, ItemMap);
    }
}


private void updateItem(Item newItem, Jurisdiction jurisdiction,
        Map<Long, Item> ItemMap) throws DAOException {

    Item currItem = ItemMap.get(newItem.getProprietorId());
    if (currItem != null) {
        //just updates currItem, copying all not null attributes from newItem
        copyProperties(currItem, newItem); 
    } else {
        //some times there is a new item
        lspDao.create(newItem);
    }
}
```

So I have two questions:

- Why is each call to synchronizeItems in the loop taking longer that the previous ones?
- Is there a better way to update rows?

I was thinking in using a stateless session, and then get all items only once (currently the query is executed once in each loop), so I'll have to call manually to the `session.update(Item)` manually, something like:

```
public void batchUpdate(List<T> list) {
    StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    for(int i=0;i < list.size();i++){
        session.update(list.get(i));
    }
    tx.commit();
}
```

Comment: call tx.flush() after your tx.commit(), so you flush the changes out of your buffer

Comment: session management should be a SB complain,not yours. Just think in terms of read/write(update) of a single object,not a chunk. For your scenario chunk is just a number (the `commit-interval`)

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I tried to use a JPAItemWriter, but for project constraints I have to use Hibernate 3.X with SpringBatch 2.2.X, which seems to expect Hibernate 4 objects, causing me some ClassCastExceptions, so my writer is "agnostic", delegating the work to a DAO

Comment: instead of read all items into `synchronizeItems` call method `synchronizeItem` and perform read/update/insert for every item you need to manage

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I've added a ´session.flush()´ for each chunk. As I'm not using transactions (if the task is interrupted, it will be started again from the first item), I think it's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have experience with Spring Batch, but these guidelines deriving from my work with pure Hibernate may help you:

1. It is certainly wrong to fetch the whole table from the database. Fetch only those items whose IDs you see in the current XML chunk, using a `where item.id in (:ids)` clause;
2. a stateless session cannot be used with persistence management functions of Hibernate (no `save`, `update`, `merge`, and so on---just `executeUpdate` allowed, which results in an immediate SQL against the database);
3. the regular, stateful Hibernate Session accumulates all the beans you have involved until either commit or an explicit `clear` (or in some special circumstances which we shouldn't discuss here).

In a nutshell, this is how the skeleton of the batch update loop should look like:

```
Session hb = ...;
Transaction tx = ...;
hb.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
hb.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
for (List<Item> chunk : chunks) {
  ... process chunk ...
  hb.flush();
  hb.clear();
}
hb.commit();
tx.close();
```

Additionally be sure to configure

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
```

(50 is a good default and it should be kept within the range from 20 to 100). Without this the JDBC Batch API will not be used.

Comment: How many IDs can I put in a IN clause? I can select a smaller chunk size if necessary, but 1000 items between parentheses seems too much.

Comment: 1000 is exactly the limit for Oracle and I think other DBs don't even have that limit. 1000 is a fine value, I have personally used it in many projects.

Comment: I'm using DB2, and the limit seems to be the same one: 1000 parameters... trying.

Comment: Note that performance won't suffer even if you go much lower, say a 100. Any querying overhead doesn't amount to much when diluted by a factor of 100.

Comment: @downvoter Could you please leave a note on your issue with this answer? I will be more than glad to improve it according to your guidelines.

Comment: The current implementation is so lame I've rewritten all DAO code, based on your advice. Now it takes a few minutes to complete the task, saveing hours.

Comment: this solution has nothing to do with SB guidelines: this way to proceed (manual tx manage, session flushing and using `in()` clause) is not a robust way to create a SB job

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci The solution is according to the [guidelines from the official Hibernate documentation, Chapter 4](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html). I personally have a number of projects using this in production, delivering robust results after 4 years of continuous use. We have never had a single complaint which would stem from this approach.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I understand you point, but if I could make work seamless Spring Batch and Hibernate 3.X. Nevertheless, my code is loosely based on this answer, I'm keeping it closer to the SB guidelines

Comment: You are following Hibernate guidelines to build up a Hibernate batch application, not [Spring Batch guidelines](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html) (or best pratice) to create a SB batch application. Guidelines are different because they use different framework. Just as an example read 1st paragraph of SB guidelines about transaction management. I'm using hibernate too with Hibernate guidelines and all works fine and I'm sure your apps do the same as mine,but with SB is a bit different

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I have added a disclaimer as the first sentence of this answer. I am trying to be as helpful as I can, and apparently my answer has indeed helped OP.

Comment: Ok. I remove downvote because you answered to OP question(s). The real problem is OP question: it's a mix of SB/Hibernate-based application and his code should be restructured according to SB guidelines

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks. I suppose that, at some level, SB is spinning this kind of loop internally, exposing only the essential callbacks to the user.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I am reading Spring Batch documentation, it seems based on the workflow where input items are consumed one at a time and only writing happens in chunks. This precludes the optimization which I am suggesting here, which is to use just one DB roundtrip to fetch 1000 existing items. Fetching one by one introduces substantial overheads. Also, each chunk is immediately committed, not just flushed to the database. This then causes escalation of the restarting logic. For some applications it is simply not acceptable to commit before the whole job is finished.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in the past. It was solved by committing each chunk update. So your approach when you commit after each 1000 updates should work.

In fact it keeps the info more and more after each 1000 updates somewhere (on hibernate side or in DB side) to be ready for rollback. So all the data is somewhere in buffer till you commit.

Comment: The current implementation lacked a `flush()` call. Adding that helped